# Playwright : waitForResponse timesout even when the api call has actually completed successfully

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I am using Blazor WebAssembly SPA app.
WaitForResponse is failing with TimeoutError, even when before the timeour
API has completed successfully.
On click of button, my app makes an API call.

What am i doing wrong here ?

```
await Promise.all([
                page.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url() === 'https://XXXXXX.net/api/Organization/GetTokenFromMobile' && resp.status() === 200),
                page.locator('button.btn-success', { hasText: 'GetToken' }).click()
            ]);
```

Comment: Please specify expected behavior...

Comment: I thought the heading was quite clear, but anyway.
I was expecting it to not time out, since the response already comes back with 200(OK)

Comment: Try to separate the calls in the correct order. `await Promise.all` does something in parallel.